# Python subset file directories with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to append matching directories from a list to an empty list based on user input.  The directory format is
/a/b/c/d/e/f/

a-f can have any alphanumeric or be empty.  The user can enter one or more inputs and should match all directories with those inputs.  For example can enter 'a' and leave b-f empty, but all directories with 'a' input will match regardless of b-f.

I thought I had it working, but if there are any spaces in a user specified path it returns no match.

What I have tried:
This works:

```
a = r'.*?(?iLmsux)\s*'
b = 'thisWorks'
c =  r'.*?(?iLmsux)\s*'
d =  r'.*?(?iLmsux)\s*'
e =  r'.*?(?iLmsux)\s*'
f =  r'.*?(?iLmsux)\s*'

path = re.compile(r"/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/" % (a,b,c,d,e,f))
y = r'//thisWorks/gf e /8900_=!/ 90[//'

if path.search(y):
    print "match found"
else:
    print 'no match'
```

This also works:

```
x = re.compile('this works')
if x.search('this works'):
    print 'match'
```

But this doesn't work:

```
a = r'.*?(?iLmsux)\s*'
b = 'this does not'
c =  r'.*?(?iLmsux)\s*'
d =  r'.*?(?iLmsux)\s*'
e =  r'.*?(?iLmsux)\s*'
f =  r'.*?(?iLmsux)\s*'

path = re.compile(r"/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/" % (a,b,c,d,e,f))
y = r'//this does not/////'

if path.search(y):
    print "match found"
else:
    print 'no match'
```

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: Have a look at [**`glob`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)

Comment: @Jan thank you for the suggestion.  I do not believe my current situation allows glob because I am working out of a HEC-DSS database file that contains the directories.  I am working in [DSSVue](http://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-dssvue/), which is a java based program and uses jython for user defined functions.